# Firefox notifications timeout

Tags: firefox, notifications

When I receive a notification, a window pops up and stays for around 4 sec.

How can I change the timeout to something else ?

I have Firefox ESR 52

Also, can I change the background color of the notifications ?
Perhaps in UserChrome.css ?

Comment: It would be better to include one or more screenshots of a typical notifications.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the timeout to something else ?

This value is hard-coded. See [Mozilla DXR](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/alerts/resources/content/alert.js#151). To adjust it, grab the Firefox Sources make your changes and recompile.